# Need to read a series of .txt files in a folder and write them in to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

So i have a folder C:\IDFolder contains a series of .txt file named ID01 to ID99. Each file had 5 lines for ID,password, name, bla..bla..
And I have a windows forms contain a datagridview table named profile. On the same form that had the table, there's a "import" button. When a user clicks the "import" button, this should work : Each rows on the table will imports data from the .txt series. 
Ex:

The first row will have: ID01/Password/Name/.... (take from the ID01.txt) and the second row :     ID02/Password/Name/.....(take from the ID02.txt)

I've tried

```
foreach (System.IO.File.Exist(@"C:\IDFolder")
```

and this is what i have in mind:

```
foreach ( /* file in C:\IDFolder */)
        {
            this.pro.Rows.Add(/*filename*/ , /*first line in file*/ , ....)
        }
```

but it declared an error. Now, i'm stuck. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: i think you should first look the for each syntax

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Comment: put the foreach loop code in detail

Comment: i've edited my question. Please consider checking it out.

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: @user3032547 is it resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont mind, just crate one class to save your record file. Let's say ID class. Iterate every file, read and store it into ID class and return the list of the data. You could bind the list into your data grid view.

Here the codes :

```
public class ID
{
    public string id {get; set; }
    public string UserName {get; set; }
    public string Password {get; set; }        
    public string Bla1 {get; set; }
    public string Bla2 {get; set; }
}

public IList<ID> GetAllID()
{
    string folderName = @"c:\IDFolder";
    string fileName = "ID0";
    string formatFile = ".txt";
    IList<ID> IDs = new List<ID>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        string indexFile = (i + 1).ToString();

        string filePath = folderName + "\\" + fileName + indexFile + formatFile;

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string[] result = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            ID id = new ID();
            id.id = result[0];
            id.UserName = result[1];
            id.Password = result[2];
            id.Bla1 = result[3];
            id.Bla2 = result[4];

            // add id into IDs
            IDs.Add(id);
        }
     }
     return IDs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no onliner for this. (As far as I know). You should use retrieve all files using Directory. and after that open the file with File.Open

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\IDFolder", "*.txt"))
{
  /* your code */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    this.pro.Rows.Add(/*filename*/ , GetFirstLine(/*filename*/,2) , ....)
}

string GetFirstLine(string fileName, int line)
{
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
       for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
          sr.ReadLine();
       return sr.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this:

```
    String path=@"C:\IDFolder";

    String [] files= System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
    List<String> ID=new List<string>();
    List<String> Password=new List<string>();
    List<String> Name=new List<string>();
    int count=0;
    int rows = 0;
    foreach (String strFileName in files)
    {
         count = 0;
       String[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFileName);
       foreach (String line in allLines)
       {

           dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
           if (allLines[count].Split('/').Length==3)
           {                      
               dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value = allLines[count].Split('/')[0];
               dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[1].Value = allLines[count].Split('/')[1];
               dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[2].Value = allLines[count].Split('/')[2];
               count++;
               rows++;
           }

       }
    }
```

**Output:**

It will add `ID,Password and Name` from each file in given folder into `DataGridView`